# No provider for Http. Zone angular. Task Promise then Value

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to call Web API from my Angular2 class.

**service.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers  } from "@angular/http";
import { apimodel } from '../../_model/APImodel';
import Global = require('../../_utilities/constants/constants');
import { UserModel } from '../../_model/usermodel';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class services
{
    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getLogin(model : UserModel)  {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(Global.BASE_URL + '/login', model, options)
                .toPromise().then(res=><apimodel>res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error:any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error); // log to console instead
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }
}
```

**login.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from '../../_model/usermodel';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import Global = require('../../_utilities/constants/constants');
import {apimodel} from "../../_model/APImodel";
import { services } from '../../_utilities/services/services';


@Component({
    templateUrl: './_componant/login/login.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
    model : UserModel = {id : 0, email : "", password : "", username : ""};
    myform : FormGroup;
    submitted : boolean = false;
    returnUrl : string;
    response : apimodel;

    constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private services : services){

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.myform = new FormGroup({
            username : new FormControl("", Validators.required),
            password : new FormControl("", Validators.required)
        })

        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login(model : UserModel){
        this.submitted = true;
        if(this.myform.valid)
        {
            this.services.getLogin(model).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log(error));
            //Call Web Service to login
            console.log(this.returnUrl);
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        }
    };
}
```

**Module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule, PipeTransform }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './_componant/app/app.component';
import { appRouterModule } from './app.route';
import { LoginComponent } from './_componant/login/login';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './_componant/registration/registration';
import { services } from './_utilities/services/services';



@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ,appRouterModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrationComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers: [services]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see, I have injected services class properly as well as add Http correctly in service.ts

I am getting following error in console:
[image]

Comment: are you using httpclient or old http module?looks like old http module to me.Why don't you try using Observable instead of converting to Promise?

Comment: Ubiquitous Developers check my answer for httpclient example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included HttpModule in your module.ts file.

```js
import { NgModule, PipeTransform }      from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './_componant/app/app.component';
import { appRouterModule } from './app.route';
import { LoginComponent } from './_componant/login/login';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './_componant/registration/registration';
import { services } from './_utilities/services/services';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, appRouterModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrationComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers: [services]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

> You have missed
>
> **import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';**
>
> And
>
> imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, **HttpModule**, appRouterModule],

Answer (score 1):

you need to import `HttpModule` like below in your app.module

`import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";`

and then use it in the `imports` section

`imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ,appRouterModule,HttpModule]`

However if you are using Angular 4 and want to use the new `HttpClientModule` which will be followed in later versions of angular then you can use it like below

in your app.module make the below changes

```js
import { NgModule, PipeTransform }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http;  //import the module here
import { AppComponent } from './_componant/app/app.component';
import { appRouterModule } from './app.route';
import { LoginComponent } from './_componant/login/login';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './_componant/registration/registration';
import { services } from './_utilities/services/services';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ,appRouterModule,HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, RegistrationComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
  providers: [services]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

in your **service.ts** class import and inject it like below

```js
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class services
{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }
  /// rest of the code 
}
```